# Continuity of f where f(x) =d(u,x) maps the metric space M into the real numbers

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, continuity

How do I prove that the function $f(x) = d(u,x)$ who maps the metric space $M$ into the real numbers are continuous? u is a fixed point of the metric space $M$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $d(u,x) \leq d(u,y) + d(x,y)$ and $d(u,y) \leq d(u,x) + d(x,y)$ yields that $|d(u,x) - d(u,y)| \leq d(x,y)$. Conclude.